# XLSX Package vulnerabilities found but there is no newer package

Tags: javascript, js-xlsx

I am using xlsx in my js code. It works fine from last year. Today I start getting problem and build fails. Dueto:

```
$ yarn audit: 

yarn audit v1.22.19
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ moderate: Prototype Pollution in sheetJS                               
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Package: xlsx                                                         
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Patched in: >=0.19.3                                                     
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Dependency of: xlsx                                                         
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Path: xlsx                                                         
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ More info: https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1091817                     
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

It is obvious the solution is to upgrade to version 0.19.3 or higher, but the latest vesion is 0.18.5 due to: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx?activeTab=readme.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: "The new home for SheetJS CE is https://git.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/sheetjs, a hosted Gitea instance sponsored by SheetJS LLC. SheetJS CE remains a truly open source project under the Apache 2.0 License.".

Comment: @Andy, how can I update my code with latest version?

Comment: There is documentation at that link.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is wondering what's happening with SheetJS [here's an article about the move](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/npm-package-with-14m-weekly-downloads-ditches-npmjscom-for-own-cdn/).

Comment: https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/getting-started/installation/nodejs

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. Did you know a way to audit the package in order to see if there is any vulnerability on it now? for instance on the latest 0.20.0? Many thanks.

Comment: You can still manually search e.g. the GitHub Advisory Database: https://github.com/advisories?query=sheetjs.

Answer (score 14):

As explained in the README, this project is no longer maintained on GitHub and no longer published to npm. Try to install from below link: https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.3/xlsx-0.19.3.tgz. In your package.json file add this:

```json
"xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.3/xlsx-0.19.3.tgz"
```

Comment: This package has the same issue

Comment: The above code shows how to install xlsx package as this version is not published on NPM.At the time of posting npm audit was not showing any vulnerabilities. As in 
your case if it is having the same issue check for newer versions and you can install the new package the same as the above method.
hope this will help!